# How to match consecutive dates contains multiple values and calculate the date per each calendar month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

[image]

I am trying to calculate between those two date columns which contains multiple values. I have tried to use split columns by number of characters (10) repeatedly. My data contains date values up to 4 or 5 dates in one columns however I am not able to find a way to do 2 columns respecting the order they have. I was thinking to use group by once I split them into rows.

Comment: Did any of these answers for for you? If so please accept the solution

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what you want to calculate. But I suggest doing the Group By first as it will be simpler to expand the results:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table13"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Admit Date", type text}, {"Discharge Date", type text}}),

//Group by ID
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {

    //create new table of individual dates from each subgroup
        {"Dates", (t)=>
            let 
                #"Split Admit Dates" = List.Transform(t[Admit Date], each
                        Splitter.SplitTextByLengths(List.Repeat({10}, Text.Length(_)/10))(_)),
                #"Split Discharge Dates" = List.Transform(t[Discharge Date], each
                        Splitter.SplitTextByLengths(List.Repeat({10}, Text.Length(_)/10))(_)),
                #"Result" = Table.FromColumns(
                                {List.Combine(#"Split Admit Dates")}
                              & {List.Combine(#"Split Discharge Dates")},
                                    {"Admit Date", "Discharge Date"})
            in 
                #"Result"}}),

//Expand the subtables and set the data types
    #"Expanded Dates" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Dates", {"Admit Date", "Discharge Date"}),
    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Dates", {
        {"Admit Date", type date},
        {"Discharge Date", type date}})  

in
    #"Set Data Types"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try this in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Repeat(Text.PadStart(Text.From([ID]),10),Text.Length([Admit Date])/10)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"ID"}),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Transposed Table",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
ColumnToSplitTo=List.Transform({1 .. List.Max (List.Transform(#"Merged Columns"[Merged], each Text.Length(_)))/10}, each "Column."&Text.From(_)),
#"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Merged", Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(10), ColumnToSplitTo),
#"Transposed Table1" = Table.Transpose(#"Split Column by Position"),
#"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Transposed Table1",{{"Column3", each Text.Trim(_), type text}})
in  #"Lowercased Text"
```

[image]